# ProgressDialog создается с запозданиями, а должен сразу

Tags: java, android

Заметил недавно одну вещь. `ProgressDialog` появляется только по окончании работы `onCreate`, а мне надо, чтобы он появлялся сразу, как только я вызвал функцию его появления. В `onCreate` я  тексты устанавливаю в `ProgressDialog` и провожу работу. Если закомментирую `finish()`, то диалог появится, но не завершится активность. Как исправить эту проблему?
Вот пример кода, скопированный:

```
protected static ProgressDialog progressDialog(final Context context, final String name, final String podname){
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setTitle(name);
    pd.setMessage(podname);
    // меняем стиль на индикатор
    pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    // устанавливаем максимум
    pd.setMax(2148);
    // включаем анимацию ожидания
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);

    return pd;

}
```

А вот моя активность, которая должна запустить это окошко, показывая пользователю, что происходит работа, и закрыться...(код укроченный) (проверьте -увидите белый экран место диалога)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ProgressDialog pd= Dialoger.progressDialog(this, "Загрузка...", "Загружаю...");
    pd.show();

    pd.setMessage("Гружусь...");

    Voider.Sleep(5000); //ФУНКЦИЯ ОПИСАНА НИЖЕ
    //работа функций... которые тоже делают pd.setMessage
    finish();
```

в другом классе

```
public static Boolean Sleep(int sec){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.sleep(sec);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

//

Как мне улучшить код чтобы сразу после действия появилось это окошко? А не через время, не понятно когда...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Любые длительные задачи выполняйте в отдельном потоке, например, с помощью класса [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    ProgressDialog pd=null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
        pd.setTitle(name);
        pd.setMessage(podname);
        // меняем стиль на индикатор
        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // устанавливаем максимум
        pd.setMax(2148);
        // включаем анимацию ожидания
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //Делаем длительную работу...

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        //скрываем диалог
        pd.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо все работает, простите за запоздание с принятием правильного ответа)