# ProgressDialog не появляется что не то? (StartAct)

Tags: java, android

Почему не появляется `progressDialog` на время выполнения скрипта?

Активность:

```
package ux.uchat;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class Start_UChat extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final Context context = this;

        class StartAct extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            ProgressDialog pd=null;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pd = Dialoger.progressDialog(context, "Загрузка...", "Загружаю...");

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                Voider.Sleep(2000); //ПОЯВИТСЯ ДИАЛОГОВОЕ ОКНО НА 2 СЕКУНДЫ, НО УЖЕ ПОД КОНЕЦ(

                pd.dismiss();
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                pd.show();

                pd.setMessage("Гружу статус бар...");

                Voider.Sleep(2000);

                StatusBar.InitStatusBar(context);
                pd.setMessage("Гружу настройки...");

                SharedPreferenses sharedPreferenses = new SharedPreferenses(context, "Auth");

                pd.setMessage("Проверяю логин и пароль...");

                if (sharedPreferenses.GetStringBoolean("login")
                        && sharedPreferenses.GetStringBoolean("pass")) {

                    pd.setMessage("Достаю логин и пароль...");
                    String login = sharedPreferenses.GetString("login");
                    String pass = sharedPreferenses.GetString("pass");

                    sharedPreferenses = null;

                    pd.setMessage("Инициализирую пост:)");

                    Post.InitHttpClient(context);
                    pd.setMessage("Авторизация...");

                    if (!AccountVoider.Autoriz(context, login, pass, false)) {

                        Voider.toster(context, "Ошибка авторизации...", false, 0, 0);


                        Post.UnsetHttpClient(context);

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Autorizes.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    } else {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(context, UChat.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();
                    }

                } else {
                    Post.UnsetHttpClient(context);
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Autorizes.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
                sharedPreferenses = null;
                Voider.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        StartAct StartAct = new StartAct();
        StartAct.execute();
    }
}
```

Voider:

```
public static Boolean Sleep(int sec){
    try {
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(sec);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Dialoger:

```
protected static ProgressDialog progressDialog(final Context context, final String name, final String podname){
    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pd.setTitle(name);
    pd.setMessage(podname);
    pd.setIndeterminate(true);
    return pd;
}
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса потому, что это дубль [другого вопроса](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/444086/177345)

Comment: Нет, потамучто я ответа на этот вопрос уже какой вопрос получить не могу, щяс проверю ответ, если робит то ок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте для начала разберемся как работает AsyncTask:

1. Сразу после запуска задачи вызывается метод onPreExecute в ОСНОВНОМ потоке
2. Далее в ОТДЕЛЬНОМ потоке выполняется метод doInBackground
3. После того как doInBackground отработал вызывается метод onPostExecute в ОСНОВНОМ потоке

Взаимодействие с графическим интерфейсом разрешено только в ОСНОВНОМ потоке.

Таким образом, Вам надо создать диалог и отобразить его в onPreExecute, а скрыть - в onPostExecute.

```
class StartAct extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        ProgressDialog pd=null;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd = Dialoger.progressDialog(context, "Загрузка...", "Загружаю...");
            pd.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            //Делаем длительную работу...
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            pd.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ухты, наконецто, ответ, как долго я тебя ждал, причем все работает, спасибо!